# Is it possible to use different teams for different users?

Tags: fifa-14

My brother got FIFA 14 on my Xbox 360.  I would like to play ultimate team and other modes but without using his team.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Ultimate Team is tied to the Xbox Live account used. If you sign in with a different account to your brother, then you should have a different team.